# I'm having an error processing JSON data with GSON in Android: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying to fetch data from a server and convert one row containing a 2D array into a list, but I'm getting an error when I do this.

Here is my logcat monitor:

```
08-16 10:48:50.146 4914-4914/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 
(already on)
08-16 10:48:50.261 4914-4914/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 
using defaults: x86
08-16 10:48:51.295 4914-4914/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/InstantRun: 
starting instant run server: is main process
08-16 10:48:52.253 4914-4914/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zzbx: Making 
Creator dynamically
08-16 10:48:52.354 4914-4914/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/zygote: 
Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
08-16 10:48:52.390 4914-4914/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 11020000
08-16 10:48:52.395 4914-4914/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11302470
08-16 10:48:52.415 4914-4921/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Do 
partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=13KB
08-16 10:48:52.415 4914-4921/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: After 
code cache collection, code=26KB, data=13KB
08-16 10:48:52.415 4914-4921/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: 
Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
08-16 10:48:52.685 4914-5006/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp W/afz: 
copyMemory is missing from platform - proto runtime falling back to safer 
methods.
08-16 10:48:52.718 4914-4990/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using 
platform default
08-16 10:48:52.869 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
08-16 10:48:52.989 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-16 10:48:52.989 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
08-16 10:48:52.989 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, 
retrying without...
08-16 10:48:52.990 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
08-16 10:48:53.025 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa3f06500: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-16 10:48:53.030 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3f06500: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3f035b0)
08-16 10:48:53.127 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
W/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0::Mapper: getService: found null 
hwbinder interface
08-16 10:48:53.129 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/vndksupport: 
sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading 
/system/lib/hw/gralloc.ranchu.so from the current namespace instead.
08-16 10:48:53.239 4914-4921/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Do 
partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=49KB
08-16 10:48:53.239 4914-4921/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: After 
code cache collection, code=60KB, data=49KB
08-16 10:48:53.239 4914-4921/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: 
Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
08-16 10:48:53.240 4914-4921/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: Do 
full code cache collection, code=60KB, data=66KB
08-16 10:48:53.241 4914-4921/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: After 
code cache collection, code=0B, data=22KB
08-16 10:48:53.441 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3f06500: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3f035b0)
08-16 10:48:53.456 4914-5016/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa13f85a0: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
08-16 10:48:53.502 4914-5016/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa13f85a0: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xa26647f0)
08-16 10:48:53.568 4914-4923/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: 
Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
08-16 10:48:53.574 4914-4923/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: 
WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 6.769ms for cause ObjectsAllocated
08-16 10:48:53.591 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3f06500: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3f035b0)
08-16 10:48:53.612 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: IRenderScriptDevice::getService()
08-16 10:48:53.616 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
W/android.hardware.renderscript@1.0::Device: getService: found null hwbinder 
interface
08-16 10:48:53.616 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: IRenderScriptDevice::getService() returned 
0x0
08-16 10:48:53.617 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: Using Fallback Path.
08-16 10:48:53.658 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp D/RenderScript: 
Successfully queried cache dir: 
/data/user_de/0/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp/code_cache
08-16 10:48:53.658 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp D/RenderScript: 
Setting cache dir: 
/data/user_de/0/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp/code_cache
08-16 10:48:53.829 4914-4927/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: 
NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 3145(241KB) AllocSpace 
objects, 5(144KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 6.862ms total 
47.477ms
08-16 10:48:53.874 4914-5022/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3f06500: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3f035b0)
08-16 10:48:53.999 4914-4927/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/zygote: 
NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 1640(91KB) AllocSpace 
objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 9.294ms total 44.961ms
08-16 10:48:54.272 4914-5020/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Process: com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp, PID: 4914

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing 
doInBackground()

at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)

at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)

at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)

at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 
1 column 1 path $

at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:873)

at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:826)

at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)

at 
com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp.fetchSOCATData.doInBackground
(fetchSOCATData.java:67)

at 
com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp.fetchSOCATData.doInBackground
(fetchSOCATData.java:29)

at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 

at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 

at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was 
STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:351)

at 
com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read
(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)

at 
com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read
(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)

at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:861)

at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:826) 

at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775) 

at 
com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp.fetchSOCATData.doInBackground
(fetchSOCATData.java:67) 

at 
com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp.fetchSOCATData.doInBackground
(fetchSOCATData.java:29) 

at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305) 

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 

at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 

at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
08-16 10:48:54.838 4914-5018/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp 
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for 
com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
08-16 10:48:54.870 4914-5053/com.example.alexlevine.oceanapp I/Process: 
Sending signal. PID: 4914 SIG: 9
```

Here are the first few lines of my data: Note the complete one has many thousands of lines in rows:

```
{
 "table": {
    "columnNames": ["year", "longitude", "latitude", "fCO2_recommended", 
"time"],
    "columnTypes": ["int", "double", "double", "double", "String"],
    "columnUnits": [null, "degrees_east", "degrees_north", "uatm", "UTC"],
    "rows": [
      [2015, -8.0721, -70.533, 394.45842722124314, "2015-01-01T00:00:01Z"],
      [2015, -8.0721, -70.533, 393.47776480047287, "2015-01-01T00:01:07Z"],
      [2015, -8.0721, -70.533, 394.12413998170973, "2015-01-01T00:02:16Z"],
      [2015, -8.0721, -70.533, 393.19812650057384, "2015-01-01T00:03:22Z"],
      [2015, -8.0721, -70.533, 393.06835948609546, "2015-01-01T00:04:28Z"],
      [2015, -8.0721, -70.533, 392.560674296763, "2015-01-01T00:05:35Z"]
     ]
  }
}
```

I just want to be able to get "rows" and use it as an array list. Please note that I do not have access to manipulate this data.

Here is the snippet of my code that's causing the problem:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Type collectionType = new 
   TypeToken<Collection<OfficialSOCATPoint.TableBean>>() {}.getType();
Collection<OfficialSOCATPoint.TableBean> enums = gson.fromJson(result, 
   collectionType);
SOCATCO2DataPoint.FeaturesBean[] protoExtract = enums.toArray(new 
    SOCATCO2DataPoint.FeaturesBean[enums.size()]);
List<List<String>> dataArray = (List<List<String>>) protoExtract[3];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You defined table as a collection here `Collection<OfficialSOCATPoint.TableBean>`. Change it to single object:

```
TableBean table =  gson.fromJson(result, TableBean.class);
```